# rails generate broken with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3, nomethoderror

I am having some troubles with my Rails environment - running a command like:

```
$ rails generate scaffold_controller model_name
```

results in the following trace:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb:13:in `parse': undefined method `split' for :clear:Symbol (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:161:in `block in parse_attributes!'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:160:in `map'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:160:in `parse_attributes!'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:21:in `initialize'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/resource_helpers.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:227:in `new'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:227:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@myproject/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

As nothing in the trace seems to even be from my specific project, I'm a little stumped as to what could be going on.  As you can see, I'm running rails 3.2.13 on an rvm-installed ruby 1.9.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m getting the same error using Rails 4.0.0 and running the generator through Zeus. I’ve customised my generators a bit (switched off helpers/stylesheets/javascripts by default), but all pretty vanilla beyond that. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Sadly, no... I've just been working around it by avoiding affected generators...

Comment: Ah well. I’m going to spend a bit of time looking at it next week. I’ll post anything useful I find here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. it turns out that I had following line somewhere in my code.

```
include Term::ANSIColor
```

This code is needed for colorised Term output. But it is fine to comment it out temporarily when you need to generate or destroy scaffolds. The method or symbol 'clear' conflicts with other gems. So this probably fixes rake:erd as well.